# Solr JOIN query with facet:on

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new in solr query (solr 4.0) and I want to make a join betwen two table different and in the same time I want to apply a facet: my query like this:

```
http://solr-master/collection1/select?fq={!join+from=id+to=project_id_s}
id:*&q=[*+TO+*]&fq=nature_s=EQPX&stats=on&stats.field=nbPublication_i
&stats.field=budget_i&stats.facet=region_s&wt=json&indent=true
```

This result show me just the fields of the last table that contain the 'project_id_s' field:
If I can express my needed by sql, so I want to execute this query in solr :

```
Select  sum(myfield1),sum(myfield2),sum(myfield3)
  FROM Table& as T1, Table2 as T2
  WHERE T1.id=T2.project_id_s AND T1.field='condition1' AND T2.field='condition2'
Group BY T1.field or Group BY T2.field
```